# Java - how to stop data being edited upon an instance of it being created

Tags: java, oop

I am wondering how would I ensure that when an instance has been created that it is then impossible to change whatever is being passed through that instance. Therefore data can only can be created once.

I have a class with get and set methods of an accountNo and SortCode, how would I ensure that when this instance is called within a main method, then it can't be changed afterwords.

Thanks

Comment: read about immutable objects...

Comment: You dont need set methods if you dont want them to be changed

Comment: See also Joshua Bloch's book "Effective Java", items 15: Minimize mutability and 39: Make defensive copies when needed. Summary: no mutators, prevent subclassing, all fields final and private, make defensive copies of any mutable objects passed into or out of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Make the fields `final`.

```
final int accountNo;
```

Comment: This is helpful, but by no means sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

you need a strategy defining your objects Immutable

how:

- declare members as final
- don't provide setters
- don't let subclass to override methods

check the Immutable RGB example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html)